# iOS: Refresh Data When App is Brought to Foreground

Tags: ios, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I'm getting data off the server via JSON and displaying it on Labels.
I've added that method in viewDidLoad.

I want to refresh the data when the user opens the app again. Currently, even if I kill the app in the simulator and start the app again, it doesn't refresh.

I tried the viewDidAppear method, but it isn't being executed for some reason.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear{
        NSLog(@"Called viewDidAppear");
}
```

This is never called. I tried to minimize the app but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this tutorial - http://leejon.es/notifying-a-viewcontroller-with-uiapplicationdidbecomeactivenotification/

First, attach to the notification in the viewWillAppear method of the target view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector( appActivated: )
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object: nil];

}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self ];
}


- (void)appActivated:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self update];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can listen for notifications and respond appropriately. Try using these and decide what works for your intended workflow.

```
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
```

You can use respond to the notification like this.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object: nil queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    // LOAD JSON
}];
```

Comment: Simply adding this code to .m file doesn't work. Should I make changes to the .h declaration?
"@interface fergie_timeViewController : UIViewController"

Comment: You should put this code in `viewDidLoad`.  Did you put any code in the callback block? I suggest an `NSLog()` to test.

Comment: No, I hadn't! I didn't realize that I was supposed to put it in the function. I followed a tutorial and added it to viewWillAppear.
Now it is working great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The viewDidAppear: method takes a bool parameter wether the view was displayed with an animation which you are missing. Also you have to call the implementation of the superclass:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidAppear: animated];
   NSLog(@"Called viewDidAppear");
}
```

Comment: I made the edits but still it is only called once along with viewDidLoad.

I tried to close and restart the app, I also tried to minimize and then open the app but it did not run.

Answer (score 1):

In your app delegate implementation, there is a method called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

This method is called each time the app is launched, so I think it fits your needs. If you place your code here, it should work.

Also, be aware you should not perform a synchronous call here, because you will delay the app launch.

**EDIT:**
This method will be only called when the app launches. You could place your code inside a method, and call it from application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and then also call it from the method:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

This method will be called when the application enters the foreground, but not after the first launch, so beware.

I also think you should check the UIApplicationDelegate methods from apple developer page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
Also, check out the application state changes:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: if I minimise the app and then launch it again, will it be called again?

Comment: @PriteshDesai ok, check out my edit, I think applicationwillenterforeground may help you.

Comment: I simply pasted the function but it isn't being called. Should I make any changes in the .h file? It is a simple "@interface fergie_timeViewController : UIViewController"
Thanks

Comment: @PriteshDesai This methods refer to your AppDelegate.m class. It's name probably will not be AppDelegate, but it will certainly contain those two words (i.e. MyApplicationAppDelegate.m). Check it out.